# Access multiple private GKE clusters with Cloud Build private pools

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build, vpc

I have two clusters in GKE (staging and production) and I've setup Cloud Deploy for deploying my web application to these clusters. So far I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools) documentation but I could only get cloud build to access the staging cluster and not the production cluster.

Do I have to create a separate cloud build private pool for each cluster?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: More details are required. Are the 2 clusters in the same project? In the same VPC?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, they're in the same project. I've setup the Cloud Build private pools for the staging cluster and it's working fine but not the production cluster.

Comment: Are they in the same VPC?